# Reverse Translation Function?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

As you know **t()** function in Drupal is translation function.

**t('base value')** returns translated expression for current language.

I want to know, is there any function in Drupal that takes translated expression as a parameter and returns base value ?

```
$translated = t('base');
$base_value = reverse_translation ($translated)
```

I am searching for **reverse_translation** function

Answer (score 2):

according to [t() documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/t/7) you can get translate the string it in any langcode,it is mean you can have reverse translation

my suggestion is

```
t($string,  array(), array('langcode'=>'en'));
```

and as example
stack dont let me use persian character(I write in Fenglish but you read it persian :) )

`t('Chetori mehrdad',  array(), array('langcode'=>'en'));`

return equal of string ('Chetori mehrdad') in english  if you translate it before form English to persian (`How are you mehrdad`), this mean 'Chetori mehrdad`(persian) => 'How are you Mehrdad'(english) :)

I hope this is useful at this time ,sometimes the answers is after you need :(

Answer (score 0):

If someone is looking for version Drupal 8/9, in this case we can use:

```
$locale_string = \Drupal::service('locale.storage')->findTranslation([
    'translation' => 'Ciao',
    'language' => 'it',
]);
```